Having trouble setting up Realm DB in Android project with Hedgedog Android Studio
I'm working on integrating Realm DB into my Android project using Hedgedog version of Android Studio. However, I'm encountering issues with applying the plugin, setting the ID, and adding dependencies in the Gradle files.
I've tried various configurations, but I'm still unable to implement Realm DB successfully. Could someone please provide the necessary code snippets for both the app-level build.gradle and project-level build.gradle files?
Your help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.
